# How does the asset schema property work with img assets?

Tags: aframe

I am trying to pass an image as an asset property type to some other component (so that either a #selector or a url(url) can be passed) but it seems to take in the entire html component, instead of just the url.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame</title>
    <meta name='description' content='Hello, WebVR! - A-Frame'>
    <script src='../../global/js/aframe-v0.8.0.min.js'></script>

    <script>
        AFRAME.registerComponent('some-component', {
            schema: {
                image:  {type:'asset',      default:''},
                model:  {type:'asset',      default:''}
            },
            init: function() {
                console.log(this.data.image);   //prints out <img id="SomeImage" src="../../someDir/someFile.jpg">
                console.log(this.data.model);   //prints out '../../someDir/someModel.gltf'
            }
        });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <a-scene >
        <a-assets timeout='3000'>
            <!-- this works as an asset no problem -->
            <a-asset-item id='SomeModel' src='../../global/assets/models/gltf/UserHead/UserHead.gltf'></a-asset-item>

            <!-- this does not pass as an asset but rather an html element -->
            <img id='SomeImage' src='../../global/assets/textures/equirectangular/CloudySky.jpg'>
        </a-assets>

        <a-entity some-component='image:#SomeImage; model:#SomeModel;'></a-entity>
    </a-scene>
    </body>
</html>
```

Thought I might look to see how A-Frame handles this in the material component can't see where does the 'src' property on material come from?

```
<a-entity id='skyBox'
            geometry='primitive:sphere; radius:50; segments-height:6; segments-width:6;'
            material='shader:flat; src:#skyMap; side:back; height:2048; width:2048'>
</a-entity>
```

Material component (can't see src): https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/components/material.js

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

As per Piotr's discoveries below it looks like images are handed as a special case, as can be in the src code [here with frame 0.8.0](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-v0.8.0.js) where an image source is handed like this:

```
hash: function (data) {
    if (data.src.tagName) {
        // Since `data.src` can be an element, parse out the string if necessary for the hash.
        data = utils.extendDeep({}, data);
        data.src = data.src.src;
    }
    return JSON.stringify(data);
},
```

So basically if an image we the asset property will not handle image's properly and an additional step of grabbing the url from it via

```
data.src.src
```

OR

```
data.src.getAttribute('src');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please correct me if i'm wrong, but i think it's not in the material schema.

I think the devil's in the [component.js](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/core/component.js), which not only seems to allow you to assign a value to any given property, but also has the constructor for any component, and parses the schema.

That being said, the material does not need a `src` in the schema, as it seems to be a part of every component. Furthermore there are multiple parsers like the [assetParse](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/core/propertyTypes.js), or [src-loader](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/utils/src-loader.js), checking whether an attribute is a html element, or even a video / image asset.

---

As for the material part, check out the dist source [code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-v0.8.0.js), where
I think what you're looking for is:

```
module.exports.updateMapMaterialFromData
```

where you can see a-frame team uses the data.src for the material, and updates the texture with it. Just give it a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (only 3 hits).

---

So when

```
module.exports.updateMapMaterialFromData('map', 'src', shader, data);
```

is called, with the given definition:

```
module.exports.updateMapMaterialFromData = function (materialName, dataName, shader, data) {
  var el = shader.el;
  var material = shader.material;
  var src = data[dataName];
  .......
```

makes `src` = `data[src]` => they make updates using a local variable src.

---

Also you can see the [src-loader](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/master/src/utils/src-loader.js) in action where the `material` system is registered, and when a `src` attribute is found out, the `validateSrc` function fires one of the two callbacks:

```
utils.srcLoader.validateSrc(src, loadImageCb, loadVideoCb);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing in the right direction. In the end it seems we will have to code an extra case for handling an img asset for now. Edited question but will accept yours as answer.

Comment: @Anthony, glad i could help, i'm almost sure that when you create a component, the constructor parses the schema ("somwhere around 491 in component.js), i hope someone from the a-frame team confirms this, or corrects me if i;m wrong :)